# Earning from social media while on a blue card

Tags: germany, blue-card, freelance

Is it legal to have a full time job on a Blue Card in Germany, and also earn on the side from social media accounts like Instagram and YouTube?

Answer (score 3):

I am assumming that a "Nebentätigkeit" is not allowed on your Blue Card in general, otherwise you would not be asking.

Germany defines working as, well... working. So if you generate passive income *without* working, then that is allowed. That might be because you own stocks, maybe have a house in your home country you rent out, or maybe you have a social media channel that already exists, that generates money from old content.

However, *producing new content* for said channel is *work*. It would be considered a hobby if you did not monetize the channel and make no money from it, but as soon as you start to make money, it is a "Nebentätigkeit".

Your Blue Card should have a note about "Beschäftigung", what is allowed and what is not and when that restriction ends. I think the default is after 2 years of working in the designated job you can freelance. You could also ask for a permission to do so prior to that, but you should really do that through a lawyer who knows the very specific details and I guess lawyer fees would easily eat up any profit you could make from social media if you are just starting out.

So to summarize:

- owning previously existing content is passive income
- actively creating content for social media is a *hobby*.
- actively creating content for social media *that gets monetized* is a *job*

Unless your Blue Card is somehow special or you have a specific permit for an exception, having a side job is not allowed.